Proving that the closure of a set is closed directly
Currently working through Rudin's principle's of mathematical analysis. I am trying to prove directly that the closure of a set is closed but am hitting a wall on one part of the proof. Namely, if we take the closure of a set to be the union of the set itself with the set of its limit points. We can say:
Let $x$ be a limit point of $\bar{E}$. then $\forall r>0,\ N_r(x) \cap \bar{E}$ is nonempty. By definition of $\bar{E}, (N_r(x) \cap E) \cup (N_r(x) \cap E')$ is nonempty. This implies at most one of these is empty.

if $N_r(x) \cap E$ is nonempty, $x$ is limit point of $E \implies x \in E' \implies x \in \bar{E}$
if $N_r(x) \cap E'$ is nonempty, $x$ is limit point of $E' \implies ....$


is where I'm not sure how to proceed.

edit: I'm only using the most basic definition of closed. Namely, if a point p is a limit point of the set, then p is in the set.

Use MathJax to write math in your question, it is currently unreadable.

What is the definition of closure that you are using?

@Didier the union of set with the set of its limit points. E-bar = E union E' (where E' is the set of limit points of E)

Show that complement of the closure is open.

@Anacardium so there's no way to do the direct proof how I've outlined here?

To prove it "directly", you need a very precise definition of what a closed set is. If closed means complement is open, then you should do as @Anacardium. If closed means $\overline{B} = B$, then you should prove that $\overline{\overline{B}} = \overline{B}$. What is "closed" to you?

@user8083$:$ Obviously there is a direct way as well. Choose an element $x \in \overline {E}'.$ Then for any $r > 0$ $N_r (x) \cap \overline {E} \neq \varnothing.$ Choose $y \in N_r(x) \cap \overline {E}.$ Choose a neighbourhood $N_s (y) \subseteq N_r (x).$ Note also that $y \in \overline E.$ Now use the definition of closure and conclude that $x \in \overline E.$

@user8083$:$ Since $y \in \overline E$ it follows that $$(N_s (y) \cap E) \cup (N_s (y) \cap E') \neq \varnothing.$$ But since $N_s (y) \subseteq N_r (x)$ you have $$(N_r (x) \cap E) \cup (N_r (x) \cap E') \neq \varnothing.$$ So according to your definition of closure it follows that $x \in \overline E.$

If we take the definition of closure to be $\overline{E} := E^{\prime} \cup E$, then, in order to show that $\overline{E}$ is closed you may simply show that complement $\overline{E}^{c}$ of this set is open.
Take arbitrary $x \in \overline{E}^{c}$. It means that $x \notin E$ and $x \notin E^{\prime}$. We conclude that there exists the neighborhood $N(x)$ such that $N(x) \cap \overline{E} = \varnothing$ and hence $N(x) \subset \overline{E}^{c}$ so $\overline{E}^{c}$ is open.
Remark: Why $x \notin E$ and $x \notin E^{\prime}$ implies that $x\notin \left(E^{\prime} \right)^{\prime}$ ?
Suppose for contradiction that $ x\in \left(E^{\prime} \right)^{\prime}$. It means that every neighborhood $N$ of $x$ contains some point $y \in E^\prime$. $N$ is open, so some neighborhood $V(y) \subset N$. But $y \in E^{\prime}$, so $V(y)$ contains some point of $E$. Therefore every neighborhood of $x$ contains some point of E, which is a contradiction.

You don't specify a definition for "closed set", but it appears from your attempt that you are trying to use the characterization that $C$ is closed if ${\rm Cl} C = C$.
In this case, the proof is quite trivial. Let $E$ be an arbitrary set. To show that ${\rm Cl} E$ is closed, we just show that ${\rm Cl} {\rm Cl} E = {\rm Cl} E$. Since the closure of a set always contains the set (if you consider the closure as the union of a set and its limit points), then we just need to demonstrate that ${\rm Cl} {\rm Cl} E \subseteq {\rm Cl} E$. For this purpose, let $x \in {\rm Cl} {\rm Cl} E$. Then every basis element $B_d (x, \varepsilon > 0)$ intersects ${\rm Cl} E$, say at the point $y_\varepsilon$. Now, $B_d (x, \varepsilon)$ is indeed also a neighborhood of $y_\varepsilon \in {\rm Cl} E$, so it must intersect $E$. Therefore, $x \in {\rm Cl} E$, as desired. (This in fact is true in any topological space; instead of considering basis elements of the form $B_d (x, \varepsilon)$, take arbitrary neighborhoods $U$ of $x$.)
With regards to your attempt, you have let $x$ be a limit point of ${\rm Cl} E$, and want to show that $x \in {\rm Cl} E$. Let us assume for the sake of contradiction that $x \notin {\rm Cl} E$. Then there exists some basis element $B_d (x, \varepsilon_0 > 0)$ that is disjoint from $E$. Such a basis element must also be disjoint from ${\rm Cl} E$, for if not, an element in their intersection bears witness to the fact that the basis element intersects $E$ itself. Therefore, we have arrived at a contradiction, since $x$ was assumed to be a limit point of ${\rm Cl} E$.
